# Django rest framework user registration : Update django user database after the email verification is done

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I am trying to register the user by sending an OTP to their mail. Consider the following usual:

1. the user posts a request for registration with an email, password. (email mapped to the username of Django).
2. Django creates the user and the user gets the OTP for verification. If the user verifies, an 'is_verified' field will be set to true.

Now, If the user doesn't verify himself with the OTP, I can't get around the following issues. Please suggest a workaround.
---> Any other user can now not use the same email for registration, as email already exists in the database.

I want the user to be updated in the database only after the user has successfully verified the otp.

Comment: This will add complexity to your application. If you want to keep control of unverified users, you can set some sort of a timeout for that. For example, if a user doesn't verify the account in a day, you just remove the account so that email can be used again.

Comment: Yes, looks like timeout is a good choice. But how Django will know when to clean up the database? Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: You need to use a library like celery or django q.